# PowerPivot Manage Data Refresh Error

Tags: powerpivot

I am getting an error message when i click on Manage Data Refresh for PowerPivot workbook.

> ERROR
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.

Here is ULS Log.

> EXCEPTION: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetContainingList(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrFileUrl, Boolean bFile, Boolean bIsDocLib)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_DocumentLibraryId()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_InDocumentLibrary()     at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration.Redirector.Utils.CheckSPUserPermission(String
>   srcUrl, SPBasePermissions perm)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the cliams....

It's doesn't support to setup PowerPivot on Claims Based authentication, PowerPivot for SharePoint only supports SharePoint web applications that are configured for classic-mode authentication. But you can refer to the following article to see if this help:
All about Claims based Authentication, Power Pivot Setup and Data Refresh: http://prashanthkn.blogspot.in/2011/01/all-about-claims-based-authentication.html

check this blog, this one have the solution for access denied.
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijay/archive/2011/07/22/sharepoint-2010-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-e-accessdenied.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm using claims based authentication on multi-server farm. I think that's the problem.